# how to find middle node in singly linked list without traversal?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

how to find middle node in singly linked list without traversal ?

is it possible in first place ?

In One traversal I Use the traditional method of using 2 pointers one which jump's 2 positions and other which jump's one position ..is there any other approach to find middle node in one traversal

Comment: i think it is cheat. there will be one loop, but the amount of actions is same as if you would traverse it two times.

Comment: @Audrey I totally agree. Whoever came up with this typical "smart" answer needs to be slapped :)

Answer (score 16):

No, it's not possible.  The addresses of the nodes are arbitrary, so there's no way of knowing them without traversing them.

Answer (score 16):

```
public void findMiddleNode() {
    Node n1 = headNode;
    Node n2 = headNode;
    while(n2.getNext() != null && n2.getNext().getNext()!= null) {
        n1 = n1.getNext();
        n2 = n2.getNext().getNext();
    }

    System.out.println("middle node is "+n1.getKey());
}
```

Comment: How is this really efficient compared to just parsing the whole thing first and come back to the middle with a count? Isn't it the same number of steps?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can if you are controlling all aspects of the list's adds and deletes.

If you maintain a reference to what is considered to be the midway node during add or deletes then it can be done. There are couple cases that have to be handled. In addition, there are scenarios such as where there is an even number of elements to consider. What will be the midway node in such a situation? ect.. ect..

So you really aren't *finding* the midway node, but rather, tracking it.

Comment: I like this idea, but you will still have to traverse the list further than you normally would on half of the inserts, because when you add a node before the middle node, you may need to keep going to find the node that comes right before the middle node.

Comment: This is only of any benefit if you're only appending/deleting nodes at head or tail.  If you're doing arbitrary inserts/removals, then you would need to work out whether you're doing so before or after the middle node, which requires traversal.  O(n) insertion/removal doesn't sound like a very useful linked-list!

Comment: Also, on deletion you'd have to find the middle again, since it's singly linked and you can't step backwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
List list = new LinkedList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    list.add(String.valueOf(i));
}

int end = list.size() - 1;
int start = 0;
while (start > end) {
    start++;
    end--;
}
if(start == end) //The arrays length is an odd number and you found the middle
    return start;
else //The arrays length is an even number and there really isn't a middle
    //Do something else here because you have an even number
```

I saw this code on some other solution page... Is this not another method where the list is being singly traversed!?

Comment: SINGLY linked list. Cannot do end--.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;


public class consoleApp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List list = new LinkedList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
        {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }

        int end = list.size();

        int start = 0;
        while (start< end) 
        {
            start++;
            end--;
        }

        if(start == end) 
            System.out.println(start);
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives you the index of the middle node, not the element

Comment: In your example : list.get(list.size()/2) is enough to get mid-point ,I guess.