# Regarding finding the middle element of linked list

Tags: java

I am following the below approach to calculate the middle element from the `linked list` , but I want is there any built in method or any other approach which can also find the same easily , the approach that I am following is shown bellow..

```
import test.LinkedList.Node;
public class LinkedListTest {


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //creating LinkedList with 5 elements including head
      LinkedList linkedList = new LinkedList();
      LinkedList.Node head = linkedList.head();
      linkedList.add( new LinkedList.Node("1"));
      linkedList.add( new LinkedList.Node("2"));
      linkedList.add( new LinkedList.Node("3"));
      linkedList.add( new LinkedList.Node("4"));

      //finding middle element of LinkedList in single pass
      LinkedList.Node current = head;
      int length = 0;
      LinkedList.Node middle = head;

      while(current.next() != null){
          length++;
          if(length%2 ==0){
              middle = middle.next();
          }
          current = current.next();
      }

      if(length%2 == 1){
          middle = middle.next();
      }

      System.out.println("length of LinkedList: " + length);
      System.out.println("middle element of LinkedList : " + middle);

    } 

}

class LinkedList{
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;

    public LinkedList(){
        this.head = new Node("head");
        tail = head;
    }

    public Node head(){
        return head;
    }

    public void add(Node node){
        tail.next = node;
        tail = node;
    }

    public static class Node{
        private Node next;
        private String data;

        public Node(String data){
            this.data = data;
        }

        public String data() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Node next() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return this.data;
        }
    }
}
```

### Output:-

```
length of LinkedList: 4
middle element of LinkedList : 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find middle node in singly linked list without traversal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707128/how-to-find-middle-node-in-singly-linked-list-without-traversal)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The basic algorithm would be

- Take two pointers
- Make both pointing to first node
- Increment first with two nodes and second with one, at a time.
- Loop until the 1st loop reaches the end. At this point, the 2nd will be at the middle.

Example:-

```
while ( p2.next != null ) {
    p2 = p2.next;
    if (p2.next != null) {
        p2 = p2.next;
        p1 = p1.next;
    }
}
```

It will definitely work in odd case, for even case you need to check one more condition if first point is allowed to move next but not next to next then both pointers will be at middle you need to decide which to take as middle.

Comment: @R.J I wanted to find the middle by link Hopping but I didn't know what is "Link Hopping" exactly. is this way named Link Hopping??

Comment: Dukeling's comment is true, but this answer is the most efficient. It doesn't require a length variable, which in strict embedded systems would be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the Java built in

```
LinkedList<Object e>
```

It gives you all the functionality you need like getting the length: `list.size()`, and the middle object:

```
list.get((list.size())/2);
```

Comment: I would consider this the wrong answer, although it works in the real world. When this question is asked it's generally assumed the length is not known. Imagine you were given the root node, and not the LinkedList class.

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- Have a double linked-list and go from the back and front at the same time until you get to a common point.
- Store the size of the list and simply stop when you've reached this half this size (similar to what the standard API's [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#size%28%29) does).

Other than that I don't think you can do better than your algorithm.

Comment: If I dont have the count, then I can get the count by traversing the list, and then half of this value will be the middle one. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
public Node getMiddleElement(Node head) {
    Node slow_pointer=head;
    Node fast_pointer=head;
    while(fast_pointer.next!=null && fast_pointer.next.next!=null)
    {
        slow_pointer=slow_pointer.next;
        fast_pointer=fast_pointer.next.next;
    }
    return slow_pointer;
}

Node mid_elem=PrintMiddleElement(head);
System.out.println(mid_elem.data);
```

I/P:5 10 15 25 35 25 40 O/P:25

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this question:

- Use two indexes, `first` and `second`, both initialized to 0
- Increment `first` by 1 and `second` by `2 * first`
- Set value of `first` to middle
- Loop will execute until value of `second` is less than list size

Here is code snippet for getting middle element of list or linked list:

```
private int getMiddle(LinkedList<String> list) {

   int middle = 0;
   int size = list.size();

   for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < size; j = i * 2) {
       middle = i++;
   }

   return middle;
}

LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
list.add("5");
list.add("6");
list.add("7");
int middle = getMiddle(list);
System.out.println(list.get(middle));
```