# Finding middle element of linked list with 1 pass, is this a creative "useless answer"?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose you want to find the middle node of a linked list in as efficient a way possible. The most typical "best" answer given is to maintain 2 pointers, a middle, and current. And to increment the middle pointer when the # of elements encountered is divisible by 2. Hence, we can find the middle in 1 pass. Efficient, right? Better than brute force, which involves 1 pass to the end, then 1 more pass until we reach size/2.

BUT... not so fast, why is the first method faster than the "brute force" way? In the first method, we're incrementing the middle pointer approximately size/2 times. But in the brute force way, in our 2nd pass, we're traversing the list until we reached the size/2th node. So aren't these 2 methods the same? Why is the first better than the 2nd?

```
//finding middle element of LinkedList in single pass
          LinkedList.Node current = head;
          int length = 0;
          LinkedList.Node middle = head;

          while(current.next() != null){
              length++;
              if(length%2 ==0){
                  middle = middle.next();
              }
              current = current.next();
          }

          if(length%2 == 1){
              middle = middle.next();
          }
```

Comment: why do you have to keep track of `length` and do lots of `%` operations? can't you just use tortoise-hare algorithm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975432/regarding-finding-the-middle-element-of-linked-list

Comment: The more interesting application of the fast/slow traversal is cycle detection.  If you reach the end of the list with the fast traversal there is no cycle.  If you find yourself passing the slow pointer you have found a cycle.

Answer (score 8):

If we modify the code to be:

```
      while(current.next() != null){
          current = current.next();
          middle = middle.next();
          if(current.next() != null){
              current = current.next();
          }
      }
```

Now there are fewer assignments since `length` does not have to be incremented and I do believe this will give an identical result.

At the end of the day both solutions are O(N) so it is a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 4):

As **@Oleg Mikheev** suggested, why can't we use [Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare) to find the middle element, as follows:

```
private int findMiddleElement() {
        if (head == null)
            return -1; // return -1 for empty linked list
        Node temp = head;
        Node oneHop, twoHop;
        oneHop = twoHop = temp;
        while (twoHop != null && twoHop.next != null) {
            oneHop = oneHop.next;
            twoHop = twoHop.next.next;
        }
        return oneHop.data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer has multiple advantages:

1. Since the two methods are of the same complexity O(N), any analysis on the efficiency needs to be careful, maybe involving the specific implementation and cost model. However, for the most naive implementation, the first method can save some loop variable increments.
2. It save you one variable's space - the two pointers v.s. the length, the counter and one pointer. Also, what if it is a huge list, and the length overflowed?

However, if you consider some specific model, then the second method might be much better. If the elements are all adjacent in memory, and the list is large enough , the cache can only hold one place of continuous memory, the first method might incur some memory access cost. At the end of the day, these two methods are mostly equivalent. Of course, the technique used in the first method is more flashy, and the thought process might be useful in other contexts.

Comment: It isn't 'one pass'. There are two traversals going on: one to the end, and one to the middle. And it doesn't save a variable either: you save on `length` but you lose on `middle` and `count` (the current count).

Comment: @EJP My bad on missing a `middle`. However, why do you need a `count`? Also, since in the second loop another counter is needed, I think it still saves one variable. Also you don't need to save the original `head`, so might be even one variable less.

Comment: I didn't claim it's  1 pass, that's what most ppl who give the first method claim.. I claim it's the same as the brute force way. 1.5 passes.

Comment: Okay, I deleted that claim. Tried to find a definition of one-pass but no avail.

Comment: You have two pointers you are advancing, so there are two traversals, or 1.5 if you like. You can't call 2, or 1.5, traversals 'one pass'. You need a count so you can see whether it's divisible by two.

Comment: @HenleyChiu I agree with you, they are the same.

Comment: @EJP No you don't - just move it twice while changing the middle once.

Comment: That's why I said 1.5. 1 traversal for the pointer that gets to the end, another .5 of a traversal for the pointer that only gets to the middle. How else does it get there exactly?

Comment: @EJP just commenting on that you don't need a count. Also I removed the one-pass claim, so I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void middle(){
    node slow=start.next;
    node fast=start.next;
    while(fast.next!=null)
    {
        slow=slow.next;
        fast=fast.next.next;
    }

    System.out.println(slow.data);
}
```

10->9->8->7->6->5->4->3->2->1->

5

Answer (score 0):

This is classic job interview question.

They don't want you to come with algorithm O(n), because both of them has O(n) complexity. Common person will say, there's no way to know where is middle if i don't traverse once (so traversing once to find length, and traversing 2nd time to find middle is two passes for those who interview you). They want you to think outside of box, and figure out way you mentioned which include two pointers.

So the complexity is same, but the way of thinking is different, and people who interview you want to see that.